# Error building Go project with /cmd structure (multiple entry points)

Tags: go, compiler-errors, go-modules

Here is the directory structure of my project (`~/go/src/bitbucket.org/a/b`):

```
├── cmd
│   ├── c
│   │   └── main.go
│   └── d
│       └── main.go
├── config
│   ├── config.go
│   ├── default.json
│   └── development.json
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── log
│   └── log.go
├── main.go
```

I need to compile 2 binaries (one for each module in cmd/).

I have tried running `GO111MODULE=on go build ./cmd/c` from project root (`~/go/src/bitbucket.org/a/b`). It silently finishes without doing anything.

I also tried running `GO111MODULE=on go build -o test ./cmd/c`. It created 29kb `test` file. When i add execution rights to it and run, it finishes with error:

```
./test: 2: ./test: Syntax error: newline unexpected
```

I have tried using go 1.12.5 and go 1.11.10.
Also when i put `main.go` file from any of the cmd directories to project root  directory and build, the compiler builds it just fine (binary file size is ~33mb).

Is it possible to use 2 compiler entry points in a single project?

Comment: Your project seems to be inside your gopath, so you don't need to turn modules on. I don't think that you have a compile error, if the program compiles. So what is inside of your main files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `go install ./...` and it will create the executables in $GOPATH/bin directory if you are looking to get the executables

And regarding the multiple compiler entry points, you can. You can build using `go build ./cmd/c ./cmd/d .` but you cannot get the executables as per the [GO Documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies) `-o` can be only used in the case of single package. Instead you can write a [makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) to get all the executables with a single make target.

And regarding the error that you are seeing, I would need more information. When I tried to build a sample application, everything works fine. I am not using GO111MODULE flag though.

[image]

1. `go build` gives me *stackoverflow* executable
2. `go build -o test ./cmd/c` gives me *test* executable
3. `go build ./cmd/c` gives me *c* executable

For your convenience I uploaded the project to [github repo](https://github.com/nihanthd/stackoverflow/tree/multiple-entry-points)

Comment: Thank you. Setting package name to `main` in main.go files inside cmd directory fixed my problem. I had "package c" and "package d" there before.